# how to insert nodes in xml string file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have an XML string .that contain elements like message format, attribute collection, input, output. i want to add all the nodes and its value from output element to attribute collection element .for that what i have to do..?first take all the values from output element and store in one dictionary and add into attribute collection or any straight way is there..?all the help appreciated.. the following is my XML string

```
<MessageFormat  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<AttributeCollection>
<BUCODE>1</BUCODE><ClientCode>1</ClientCode><IsPaid>false</IsPaid> 
</AttributeCollection>
<Input>
<qty>4</qty>
</Input>
<Output>
<Soid>43</Soid>
</Output>
</MessageFormat>
```

so i want to add this node (soid. may be more than one node)from output to attribute collection.

Comment: *straight way* is as you described..

Answer (score 0):

A way to make it easier to do is to create a new XmlDocument from your xml string. Then you can manipulate your xml data using the xml api.